# python pandas.DataFrame.to_csv newline issue

Tags: python, pandas

Greeting Dear community.

I need to write a python pandas.DataFrame into csv
I try to use something like this:

```
dfPRR.to_csv(prrDumpName,index=False,quotechar="'",quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

It works fine in some sample but for other sample with long string. I encounter the issue that one record breaks into 2 or 3 different line.

what I want my output file:

```
'RcdLn','GrpPIR','w_id','fwf_id','part_typ','l_id','head_num','site_num','filename'
'2','0','01','demo_fwf_id','demo_part_typ','demo_l_id','1','0','longdemofilename'
'1100','1','01','demo_fwf_id','demo_part_typ','demo_l_id','1','0','longdemofilename'
'2198','2','01','demo_fwf_id','demo_part_typ','demo_l_id','1','0','longdemofilename'
'3296','3','01','demo_fwf_id','demo_part_typ','demo_l_id','1','0','longdemofilename'
```

Instead what I get...the file breaking into two seperate line::

```
'RcdLn','GrpPIR','w_id','fwf_id','part_typ','l_id','head_num','site_num','filename'
'2','0','01','demo_fwf_id
','demo_part_typ','demo_l_id','1','0','longdemofilename'
'1100','1','01','demo_fwf_id
','demo_part_typ','demo_l_id','1','0','longdemofilename'
'2198','2','01','demo_fwf_id
','demo_part_typ','demo_l_id','1','0','longdemofilename'
'3296','3','01','demo_fwf_id
','demo_part_typ','demo_l_id','1','0','longdemofilename'
```

Is there an option to tell to_csv use a specific record delimitor ?
I do not see that option in documentation of to_csv

What my goal is to create a csv and then a loader program will load the csv
As for now, the loader program cannot load the file when this happens. As it is not able to tell the record is finish or not..?

I see other sample file that the record does not break into 2 or 3 lines when the string is not as long. This is the desired behavior. 
How I can enforce this ??

Comment: Are you sure this is not an issue with how the line is displayed in your editor? (eg long line that is wrapped)